# android ListView adapter method getViewTypeCount() not fire when adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-listview, listview-adapter

I want my listview load every 10 item and not want my listview reuse item.

1.I load 10 item and set adapter to listview and in adapter class i call method getViewTypeCount() like this.
(current in itemList is has 10)

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
```

2.I debug in getViewTypeCount() it return value 10.

3.Then i add new 10 item to itemList(current in itemList is has 20) and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

4.When i scroll my listview down it work but when i scroll up it's error(unfortunately)

5.I found the problem because getViewTypeCount() not fire after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() it's not return 20 (i know because i test return 500 in getViewTypeCount() it's work and not error.)

6.I want my list view load every 10 item and i don't want my listview reuse position. How to solve it's?.

**Edit**

this is my adapter class

```
public class ContentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ContentInfo> Content;
private LayoutInflater Layf;

public ContentListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContentInfo> content){
    this.context = context;
    this.Content = content;
    this.Layf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Content.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Content.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return Content.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = Layf.inflate(R.layout.content_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView img_ContentImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_ContentImage);
    TextView tv_ContentName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ContentName);
    TextView tv_ContentDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ContentDate);
    TextView tv_ContentViews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ContentViews);

    if(img_ContentImage != null){
        if(Content.get(position).getPicture().length() > 0)
            new DownloadImageViewTask(img_ContentImage).execute(Content.get(position).getPicture());
    }
    if(tv_ContentName != null)
        tv_ContentName.setText(Content.get(position).getTitle().replace(" "," ").replace("-", "–"));
    if(tv_ContentDate != null) {
        if(Content.get(position).getPublishDate().length() > 0) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                Date dt = sdf.parse(Content.get(position).getPublishDate());
                String year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", new Locale("th", "TH")).format(dt);
                String byear = (Integer.parseInt(year) + 543) + "";
                tv_ContentDate.setText((new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", new Locale("th", "TH")).format(dt)).replace(year, byear));

            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
    if(tv_ContentViews != null){
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        tv_ContentViews.setText(formatter.format(Content.get(position).getViews()));
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: do you really have 10 different views in your adapter? Are you sure you are not mistaking getViewTypeCount with getCount?

Comment: To prevent a view to be reused, you must implement your own adapter.

Comment: you can remove getViewTypeCount

Comment: Pleas see my adapter in edit and tell me what worng with it's

Comment: if first i load 20 item it's work well and not reused. But i want to load every 10 item.

Comment: @blackbelt if i remove getViewTypeCount it's work but my list view is reused position i not want my listview reused position.

Comment: As @blackbelt told you, you confused the getViewTypeCount with getCount. About the reuse, just remove this if (convertView == null) from the getView method

Comment: I strongly suggest you to keep the android recycle behaviour

Comment: @blackbelt i want not to use recycle because when i scroll listview up or down the picture of item in listview changed not smooth.

Comment: first solution i found not use notifydatachange() method but use set adapter again to list view it's fix my promblem but when set new adapter listview scroll to first item.

Answer (score 2):

`getViewTypeCount()` **only** called when you call setAdapter.